Science fiction not in question, but in comments
There's a recent question that was rewritten (very well!) to be relevant to cognitive science, but then in the comments it becomes clear that the asker isn't looking for scientific information relevant to the current state of knowledge, but an answer to a very specific (and not particularly tied to reality) set of quite science-fictional circumstances.  Should it be flagged as off-topic if the question itself isn't off-topic, but the kind of answer the asker is interested in is?

I'd say kill the comments and keep the question (and if bad answers come along, downvote them)

I handled your flag and will clean up the comment thread. Thanks for bringing this to my attention! Chat is a better place for such discussions. Should you or the OP need the comments, let me or another mod know. We can still get to them.

Thanks Josh--will try to keep from derailing so far in the future.  It took me a bit by surprise, given how well the question was rewritten to address topicality concerns!

No problem Krysta! Thanks for helping to keep the site clean and on-topic! :-)
